# (R or EXCEL) Rename variables in a column to the variables in another column

Tags: r, excel

I'm a beginner in R and am looking for some help in either Excel or R.

I have an excel sheet with two columns (all text).

- Column1 has around 100,000 rows and is a list of lengthy names.
- Column2 has around 500 rows and is a list of shortened names.

**The requirement:** if a cell in Column1 contains any of the text strings in Column2, I need to rename the cell in Column1 to the string from Column2. All of the strings from Column2 are unique, so there shouldn't be an issue in overlap.

I couldn't figure it out in Excel because the cells aren't exact matches and Excel's approximate match was too inaccurate to use. I considered doing it in R, but the columns have different numbers of rows, which left me stumped. Would greatly appreciate any help possible. Please let me know if I should include more/additional details. Thank you!

This is an example of the format in R (except the columns are separate dfs because of the different number of rows)

```
Column1 <- data.frame(Full_Name = c("Geico Auto Insurance",
                  "Geico Motorcycle Insurance",
                  "Geico Commercial Auto Insurance",
                  "State Farm Car Insurance",
                  "State Farm Life Insurance"))
Column2 <- data.frame(Group_Name = c("Geico ",
                                 "State Farm",
                                 "Allstate"))
```

More: [what the example looks like in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXdGj.png)

Comment: Hi Panon,  Just thinking about the logic.  What would "Geico State Farm" map to?  Perhaps "Geico" because working from left to right, that's the first one it finds?

Answer (score 0):

We may create a regex to capture the word from 'Column2' 'Group_Name'

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
Column1 %>% 
   mutate(New_Name = str_replace(Full_Name, 
     str_c(".*(", str_c(Column2$Group_Name, collapse="|"),  ").*"), "\\1"))
```

-output

```
                         Full_Name   New_Name
1            Geico Auto Insurance     Geico 
2      Geico Motorcycle Insurance     Geico 
3 Geico Commercial Auto Insurance     Geico 
4        State Farm Car Insurance State Farm
5       State Farm Life Insurance State Farm
```

Answer (score 0):

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

You can do it in several steps :

1. Create a vector for column 2

> short_name_vct <- unique(df$GroupName)

2. Create a function

> ```
> get_match <- function(string) {
>
>
> str_detect(stringr, short_name_vct)[short_name_vct]
>
> }
> ```

3. Then just use `dplyr`

> df %>% mutate(new_col = get_match(full_name))

Answer (score 0):

```r
fuzzyjoin::regex_left_join(Column1, Column2, by = c("Full_Name" = "Group_Name"))
#                         Full_Name Group_Name
# 1            Geico Auto Insurance     Geico 
# 2      Geico Motorcycle Insurance     Geico 
# 3 Geico Commercial Auto Insurance     Geico 
# 4        State Farm Car Insurance State Farm
# 5       State Farm Life Insurance State Farm
```

From here, you can rename `Group_Name` and use it instead. You will find `NA`s where there is not a regex-match, so you might want to use `dplyr::coalesce` or a similar function to use the first non-`NA` value.